# Push data in array but after converting timestamp to date

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic3

Fetching data from Firestore and pushing it into an array. This is working fine but in this process I am changing timestamp format and I want this value of `timestamp` in my array and not the original one. How do I replace this value from original and push ?

My code so far:

`home.ts`

```
firebase.firestore().collection("dailyreport").where("timestamp", ">=", start)
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        var cities = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach( doc=> {

  const timeinmillsecs = doc.data().timestamp.seconds * 1000; 
  let a1 = new Date(timeinmillsecs); 
  let show_year_month_date =  a1.getFullYear()+'/'+(a1.getMonth()+1) +'/'+a1.getDate(); // 3.convert to imple date

  console.log(show_year_month_date); // ***NEED THIS VALUE IN dailyreports ARRAY 

         this.dailyreports.push(doc.data());
         console.log("Timestamp greather than 29march -- ", (doc.data()));
        });
    });
```

The screenshot of `console.log(doc.data())`

[image]

### Edit 1

Before pushing, I have assigned value like this -

```
doc.data().timestamp = show_year_month_date;
this.dailyreports.push(doc.data());
```

But it is also not working.

### Edit 2

Screenshot of `dailyreports` and `doc`:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the `this.dailyreports` array or `data.doc()` ?

Comment: this.dailyreports should have a new field or current timestamp field should be changed to desired format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to update `doc.data()`, copy the value to a new variable say `data`. Update the timestamp in `data` and then push data to `this.dailyreports`. And then console log `data` to see the object with updated timestamp that was pushed to `this.dailyreports`.

```js
firebase.firestore().collection("dailyreport").where("timestamp", ">=", start)
  .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    var cities = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const data = doc.data();

      const timeinmillsecs = data.timestamp.seconds * 1000;
      let a1 = new Date(timeinmillsecs);
      let show_year_month_date = a1.getFullYear() + '/' + (a1.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + a1.getDate(); // 3.convert to imple date

      data.timestamp = show_year_month_date;
      console.log(show_year_month_date); // ***NEED THIS VALUE IN dailyreports ARRAY 
      


      this.dailyreports.push(data);
      console.log("Timestamp greather than 29march -- ", data);
    });
  });
```

Comment: `doc.data().timestamp = show_year_month_date;` , even if i console.log this, it doesnt change, can i add a new field in this array and retrieve that on `home.html` side ?

Comment: Can you console.log `doc` and share what is shows ?

Comment: i have done that, see `Edit 2`  in question, i have updated the question and added the screenshot

Comment: `data.timestamp = show_year_month_date;`  Error - cannot find name data

Comment: cant we add the value of `show_year_month_date;` in a new variable lets say `timestamp2` and push that in array ?

Comment: Yes, of course, so you will have both the original and new value in the array.  `data.timestamp2 = show_year_month_date`. But you cannot update doc.data() as it is a function and changing the result will not reflect any change to the value, so we need to use a new variable like `data` and make our changes on that new variable.

Comment: how do i do that ? `doc.data().timestamp2 = show_year_month_date; this.dailyreports.push(doc.data());` is not adding this new field in the array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210568/discussion-between-abd995-and-user2828442).